# Como fazer um 'Insert into select' com Enity FrameWork

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Olá, digamos que eu tenha um Banco de dados com uma tabela 'A' antiga mas com informações bem úteis, então eu criei uma tabela 'B' neste mesmo banco, mais atualizada e preparada para receber os dados da antiga. Tenho de Passar os dados da Tabela 'A' para a Tabela 'B' mas utilizando o entity framework, qual seria a melhor forma de realizar isso sabendo que com `'using (var db = new Db())'`  tenho acesso a todas as tabelas deste mesmo banco?

Comment: usa o comando `ExecuteSqlCommand`, por exemplo `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select into") ou "insert into select"`

Answer (score 0):

Opa não sei se te ajuda mas pode seguir desta maneira:

1. Obtenha os dados da Tabela 'A' do banco de dados antigo:

   List dadosTabelaA;
   using (var db = new Db())
   {
   dadosTabelaA = db.TabelaA.ToList();
   }

2.Mapeie os dados da Tabela 'A' para a Tabela 'B':

```
List<B> dadosTabelaB = dadosTabelaA.Select(a => new B 
{Propriedade1 = a.Propriedade1, 
Propriedade2 = a.Propriedade2,}).ToList();
```

3.Adicione os dados mapeados à Tabela 'B' no banco de dados atualizado:

```
using (var db = new Db()){db.TabelaB.AddRange(dadosTabelaB);db.SaveChanges();}
```